# How to re-render string with variable in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have some string to inject into the element in Angularjs App, but that string contain some variable in it and it needs to be substitute first before injecting it to the element or somehow with some filter that tells Angular to re-render that element again because we have some variable that is not rendered yet.

```
var string = "Hi my name is <a href="{{url}}">{{username}}</a>";
```

Now when I injected that into an HTML I get it like this

https://webmaker.org/%7B%7Blang%7D%7D/privacy

```
Hi my name is <a href="%7B%7Burl%7D%7D">%7B%7Busername%7D%7D</a>
```

I believe that this will need to be re-render somehow?

---

Sorry about missing context.

So this is in `myapp.html`

```
<span ng-bind-html="'string' | i18n">
```

The HTML is output correctly here, but because that `string` variable contain some variable in it too and it's not being render correctly (Not HTML part that is not render, but the variable).

Comment: what's the original url?

Comment: That url is available in $rootScope @Tules ?

Comment: You need to provide more context in your question. Don't just guess at what you think the solution is while providing minimal information.

Comment: @Tules, The thing is that I'm trying to inject some string from some JS library (i18n library) where I have all the strings in a `js` file. Now when I load some of the string to inject them in the DOM it will work fine, but only those with variable in it will not being render?

Comment: I'm not sure what other context should I provide in here to make it more clear? -- Any variable that I have within the scope should just rerender I guess?

Comment: What do you mean by "injecting" into the html? Please provide more code from your app

Comment: @Tules I'm currently using this module https://github.com/lavinjj/angularjs-localizationservice/blob/master/app/components/localize/localize.js which is doing the part of injecting itself. I'm very new to Angular, so I'm trying to look for the code where it's doing that part atm.

Comment: This isn't your app though is it? Please post the rest of the code that your wrote.

Comment: @Tules [This PR that I have](https://github.com/mozilla/webmaker-events-2/pull/29/files#diff-3f4e9d8b92fa7baab438f8fe51b62c52R344) It might be a lot to look, but this line specifically is what I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you are trying to do but I suspect whatever it is you are going about it the wrong way. I suggest you work through some very basic Angular tutorials. You will probably find that Angular has a completely different approach to the problem.

Comment: @Tules, I will keep looking into their docs, but what I'm trying to do not sure if it's currently even possible, but this is where I'm trying to have it display [in the same PR](https://github.com/mozilla/webmaker-events-2/pull/29/files#diff-35b0166c4c706321847ecf6f6a537157R26). (Sorry to link you to github).

Comment: you should write a custom directive for it because compiled html string bind with ng-bind-html will throw unsafe error...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<span ng-bind-html="'string' | i18n">
```

using [ng-bind-html](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml) creates a binding that will innerHTML the result of evaluating the expression into the current element in a secure way.

using $scope variable in your string make it unsafe, so you should use [$sce.trustAsHtml](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24sce#trustAsHtml) but this time variables in your string cannot be bind because they will not compiled...

basically you should compile your string in order to bind your variables. Here comes custom directives you can create a directive which can replace with ng-html-bind...

here is my [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/JyoOgi0gr5OCYKMqf9HY?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `{{}}` in Javascript.
Your JS should read

```
$scope.url = "http://example.com";
$scope.name = "Link name";
```

And the HTML:

```
<a href="{{url}}">{{name}}</a>
```

You should really look over the  [tutorial](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial) to reinforce your Angular knowledge

EDIT:

sorry, now I re read your question and understand. Use `ng-html-bind` (you need 1.2.x or newer)

eg.

```
<div ng-html-bind="string"></div>
```

Given that string is a `$scope` variable.
See the [docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngBindHtml)

Comment: Hi @LcLk, Thank you so much for your answer. 

I have `url` and `username` part of `$rootScope` and that part it should work no?

Comment: I'm actually using `ng-html-bind` in there. Let me paste more code in there. Sorry about that.

Comment: For rootscope I think its `{{$root.url}}` etc, but check the docs first, they aren't as bad as they are made out be: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var string = 'Hi my name is <a href="' + url + '">' + username + '</a>';
```

Comment: This will definitely work if that variable was in the same javascript file, but as I have showed you in the PR that this is from another file. :(